# What is equivalent to rfind (from python) in Java?

Tags: java, find

I need a function that will search through input from the right side. I want to find the first ")" when going from the right (instead the left like using .find).

.rfind is from python, so I need its equivalent in Java.

Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: `String#lastIndexOf`?  I think there's another, but that's the one that pops off the top of my head

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working with Strings, the method [lastIndexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-) seems to suit your needs.

Javadoc:

> Returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the specified character.
>
> The String is searched backwards starting at the last character.

Comment: I am attempting to replace the last "(" open parenthesis symbol with a tab character "\t".      Can I do this:  line.replace.lastindexOf( '(' , '\t' );
 Thank you for the advice!

Comment: @DevonPeterson That is incorrect syntax for java, to replace the last character only, you'd need to break it down into a character array or wrap it in a StringBuilder.